# checkbox post array of first value

Tags: php, html

I have a form having an array of checkboxes:

```
<div class="coll-1">
     Conceive Plus™ <input name="test[]" id="int_conceive_c" type="checkbox" value="Conceive Plus™"/>
</div>
<div class="coll-2">
     SASMAR™ Brand <input name="test[]" id="int_sasmarbrand_c" type="checkbox" value="SASMAR™ Brand"/>
</div>
<div class="coll-3">
     Silicone Lubricant <input name="test[]" id="int_silicone_c" type="checkbox" value="Silicone Lubricant"/>
</div>
<div class="coll-1">
     Water based <input name="test[]" id="int_water_c" type="checkbox" value="Water based"/>
</div>
<div class="coll-2">
     Warming Lubricant <input name="test[]" id="int_warming_c" type="checkbox" value="Warming Lubricant"/>
</div>
<div class="coll-3">
     Flavoured Lubricant <input name="test[]" id="int_flavors_c" type="checkbox" value="Flavoured Lubricant"/>
</div>
<div class="coll-1">
     Enhancement Gels <input name="test[]" id="int_enhancement_c" type="checkbox" value="Enhancement Gels"/>
</div>
```

but while posting the form, I get array that has only first value
like:

```
Array ( [0] => Conceive Plusâ„¢ [1] => Conceive Plusâ„¢ [2] => Conceive Plusâ„¢ )
```

not all the checked values.Can any one help?any help is appreciated.

Comment: for me it looks fine can you provide more information

Comment: you should add to your code var_dump($_POST['test']); when form is submitted (assuming you use post method)

Comment: var_dump($_POST['test']); gives Array ( [0] => Conceive Plusâ„¢ [1] => Conceive Plusâ„¢ [2] => Conceive Plusâ„¢ ) i dont kbnow what seems to be the problem

Comment: why is it that the values `Conceive Plus™` are repeating? that weird... your values on each checkboxes are different. i tested your html markup and rolled up my own post process and its okay, you can provide additional code by adding your php

Comment: I tried the same on another page and works fine but in this particular page it gives this output.

Comment: This happened with someone the other day, they had `<select>` tags with default value later and they kept repeating, I advise you to re-check or post your whole HTML.

Comment: Are you saying that the inputs have all the same name? Hm.